# pgadmin 4 nav tree highlight color

Tags: pgadmin

Apologies in advance if this isn't the place to ask this question. I can't figure out how to fix the highlight color of the left navigation tree in pgadmin 4. ~See attached image.~ I don't have enough reputation to post an inline image so see the imgur link instead. The problem is that both the highlight color and the text color are very light and are not readable. Its just a pain to have to click away to read them. I'm using Chrome latest on OSX.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyElD.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. there is a settings file under ~/.pgadmin that was causing this. I wasn't able to change it but rather deleting that file and reconnecting to my database solved the issue.